# How can I include fields from Base serializer in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this code

```
class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unicode = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_unicode')
    class Meta:
        fields=('unicode',)

    def get_unicode(self):
        return 'test'
```

I want to all the fields in Base serializer to come in all sub classes of it

```
class EntrySerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = ('id', 'start_time', 'end_time')
```

but it does not contain unicode in output

**Is there any way that all fields added in Base Serializer gets
automatically appended to sub classes , without manually adding name.
I just want o keep the common fields in all classes in Base**

Comment: for me , I append the 'unicode' field to the EntrySerializer fields. Since the subclass fields will override the baseclass fields, so your unicode field is disappeared.

Comment: fields got overided in EntrySerializer, add unicode in fields of EntrySerializer

Comment: @GeoJacob , is there any way that all fields added in Base Serializer gets automatically appended to sub classes , without  manually adding name. I just want o keep the common fields in all calsses in Base

Answer (score 0):

You can add the BaseSerializer's Meta.fields to the EntrySerializer's Meta.fields:

```py
class EntrySerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = ('id', 'start_time', 'end_time') + \
            BaseSerializer.Meta.fields
```

**Note:** BaseSerializer must be a subclass of a serializer (or have an attribute `_declared_fields`).  Otherwise the field `unicode` will [not be found](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/d540f0262b4b0a5f8ce628334d1a812179556002/rest_framework/serializers.py#L284-L286) (ImproperlyConfigured exception).

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this. It will include all field of base serializer.

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    base= BaseSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = ('base','id', 'start_time', 'end_time')
```